# Ant Design - Select that displays the searched value and option to add it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I know this is a long shot but in mt TS-React app I am trying to customise a ant design select component to reflect in the dropdownRender or filterOptions the search value that the user is typing, and additionally give him the option to add it if it does not already exist.
I know this is something you could do with a [mode='tag'](https://codesandbox.io/s/wjkp2e) or with a [custom dropdown](https://codesandbox.io/s/wr1qo5) but the design I'm following doesn't really work with either option.
Below I've attached a screenshot of how my component should be styled and look like. If anyone has ever encounter something similar and could share an example it would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: There's no such option in antd select to customize the option that doesn't exist the in options list. You can join the antd [discussions](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions) or you can create feature request in antd github

Comment: I thought so, thanks for your interest anyway, I'll give the library's github a look!